# Prepared statement to loop rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, prepared-statement

**Scenario:** Following up from my previous question ([Using a cursor in a stored procedure to loop rows MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498706/using-a-cursor-in-a-stored-procedure-to-loop-rows-mysql)) I am trying to do a nested prepare statement in which I input a date to the outer one, and that calls the inner, which gets data from a table.

**Code:**

```
-- Create temporary table for the Output:
drop temporary table if exists `stats`;
create temporary table `stats`
(
    col_name varchar(32) null,
    num_nulls int null,
    num_values int null
);


-- Procedure for the check:
drop procedure if exists `set_column_null_stats`;
delimiter $$
create procedure `set_column_null_stats`
(`p_col_name` varchar(128), `wanted_date` date)
begin

-- Set variables:
set @col_nme = `p_col_name`;
set @date1 = `wanted_date`;

prepare stmt from 'insert into `stats` (`col_name`) values (?);';
execute stmt using @col_nme;
deallocate prepare stmt;

-- count number of NULLS based on conditions:
set @sql_txt = concat(
            'update `stats` s join(
            select 
            count(1) as `nb`
            from `btc`
            where`btc`.`date` = ', @date1, ' and `btc`.`', @col_nme, '` is null)
            t set `num_nulls` = t.`nb` where `col_name` = \'', @col_nme, '\';');
prepare stmt from @sql_txt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

-- count number of not NULLS based on conditions:
set @sql_txt = concat(
           'update `stats` s join(
            select
            count(1) as `nb`
            from `btc`
            where `btc`.`date` = ', @date1, ' and `btc`.`', @col_nme, '` is not null)
            -- t set `num_values` = t.`nb` where `col_name` = \'', @col_nme, '\';');        
set @sql_txt = concat('update `stats` s join (select count(1) as `nb` from `btc` where `', @col_nme, '` is not null) t set `num_values` = t.`nb` where `col_name` = \'', @col_nme, '\';');
prepare stmt from @sql_txt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end$$
delimiter ;


-- Procedure for looping through rows of `wanted_columns` table:
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists `data_check_loop` $$
create procedure `data_check_loop`(`wanted_date` date)
begin

declare dateval date default null;
declare colval text default null;

-- boolean variable to indicate cursor is out of data
declare done tinyint default false;

-- declare a cursor to select the desired columns from the desired source table
declare cursor1
    cursor for
        select *
        from `wanted_columns`; 

-- catch exceptions
        declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

set dateval = `wanted_date`;

-- open the cursor
        open cursor1;
            my_loop: 
            loop
                fetch next from cursor1 into colval;
                if done then 
                    leave my_loop; 
                else  
                    call `set_column_null_stats`(colval, dateval);
                end if;
            end loop;
        close cursor1;

end $$
delimiter ;


-- Start the process with the wanted date:
call `data_check_loop`('2018-08-13');

select * from `stats`;
```

**Issue:** This code runs with no errors, but does not give me any result. If I run just the first prepared statement, feeding the variables directly one by one, it works fine. So I am guessing the problem is with my second statement.

**Question:** Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

**Obs:** The second code should loop rows from a table (wanted columns) and feed them to the first statement, one by one (alongside with the date, which should always be the same)

**Obs2:** My objective with this query is: from a table with a list of names as rows ("id1", "date1"...) I intend to read each row and use that value into another table where the names ("id1", "date1"...) are the columns, and get a sum for each of my wanted columns, of the NULL and not NULL values (also, given another constraint of the date input). Finally, for each of my original rows (table1) I will output a new row with #NULL and #notNULL.

**Ex. Table 1:**

```
Col_names
  Id1
  Name1
  Date1
  Process
  Time
  Class
```

**Ex. Table 2:**

```
Id1    Name1    Date1    Process    Time    Class
aa     test1    01/01       3       NULL      A
NULL   test2    01/02       4       NULL      b
bb     test3    NULL        3       NULL     NULL
```

**Ex. Output:**

```
Col_name    #Null    #notNull
  Id1         1          2
  Name1       0          3
  Date1       1          2 
  Process     0          3
  Time        3          0
  Class       1          2
```

Comment: You know you opening yourself to possible (blind) SQL injections vectors attacks in the prepared UPDATES queries right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland No idea, I just recently started with SQL and am trying to put together the pieces I find online. I don't even know what injections mean.

Comment: The first PREPARE (insert) is protected because you are using `execute stmt using @col_nme` you should do the same approach for the Updates.

Comment: It is possible that you don't even need to use a cursor or dynamic SQL here.  What would be wrong with doing a normal update?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ok I will try to read on that and try to fix.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sincerely, IDK. I just found other questions where cursors were use to loop the rows of a table, and that is what I tried to do. No idea if there is a better way.

Comment: Can you provide example data and expected results? I and @TimBiegeleisen are pretty sure there is a more easy approach to this.. [help for providing data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Updated.

Answer (score 1):

It's seams you want to convert columns into records end count where the values are `null` or `not null` for that column .
The process which converts columns into records is called unpivot in most database systems this is supported with `UNPIVOT()` but MySQL does not support this. 
So normally this is done with `UNION` in combination with some aggregate functions like `MAX()`, `MIX()`, `SUM()` and `COUNT()` and a `CASE END` clause to simulate `UNPIVOT()` on MySQL.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   'Id1' AS Col_name
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Id1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#Null`
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Id1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#notNull` 
FROM 
 Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'Name1' AS Col_name
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Name1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#Null`
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Name1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#notNull` 
FROM 
 Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'Date1' AS Col_name
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Date1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#Null`
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Date1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#notNull` 
FROM 
 Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'Process' AS Col_name
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Process IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#Null`
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Process IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#notNull` 
FROM 
 Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'Time' AS Col_name
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Time IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#Null`
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#notNull` 
FROM 
 Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'Class' AS Col_name
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Class IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#Null`
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Class IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `#notNull` 
FROM 
 Table1
```

**Results**

```
| Col_name | #Null | #notNull |
| -------- | ----- | -------- |
| Id1      | 1     | 2        |
| Name1    | 0     | 3        |
| Date1    | 1     | 2        |
| Process  | 0     | 3        |
| Time     | 3     | 0        |
| Class    | 1     | 2        |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fDzZWbxq9NX2e7h7YUnA7U/3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I ran by this UNION ALL procedure, but since I have a very long list of columns, and they change continuously, I started to try an automatic procedure to read them, instead of me inputting one by one manually multiple times a day.

Comment: No problem @DGMS89 this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fDzZWbxq9NX2e7h7YUnA7U/6 is a dynamic unpivot method which generates a SQL query based on the number of columns.. I made the steps visible so it more easy to follow whats going on.

Comment: Many Thanks. I will try to add my date constraint and run it.

Comment: One question: in the query, I see you left space for passing my "table1" which has the data (as rows) for the column names. I just do not understand how to connect to the table where I will retrieve the #nulls and #notnulls.